# How to change phpmyadmin username from root to something else?

Tags: 13.04, server, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I can't seem to find a resource in the internet that explains how to do this from the command line or phpmyadmin. I'm using Ubuntu Server 13.04 in Amazon EC2.

Comment: I have no idea of how that software works, but I know how to create users for MySQL. If that is what you want to, just let me know and I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do what you do on the Linux system running your phpmyadmin:

- Keep the root account as is.
- Create other users with appropriate permissions for their roles.
- From now on use those for normal activities, and the root only when necessary.

Comment: I'm agree with that. But **how**?

Comment: @Lucio: by implementing the good old [RTFM method](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management)